# How to remove few unwanted column in WPF 4.5 Datagrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I m using XAML written below

```
<Window x:Class="ERP.WinApp.Views.Admin.Patients"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Patients" Height="auto" MinWidth="1024" Width="1024" ShowInTaskbar="False" Icon="/ERP.WinApp;component/Images/patient.png" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Grid>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="1" Name="gridPatients" ></DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And the Code behind written below

```
namespace ERP.WinApp.Views.Admin
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Patients.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Patients : Window
    {
        public Patients()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<Patient> list = new List<Patient>();
            list = // Populate it through some method
            gridPatients.DataContext = list;
        }

    }
}
```

Patient class is having few simple properties

```
public class Patient
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string FullName { get{ return this.FirstName+ " " +this.MiddleName+ " " +this.LastName; } }

        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

        public int Age { get { return DateTime.Today.Year - this.DOB.Year; } }

        public char Gender { get; set; }
    }
```

When I run the app my datagrid is having all columns with data in it while if i want to have few columns only like skipping Id and age and first,middle,last name then what is the best way.

I think doing this is bad way for each column i want to hide

```
gridPatients.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `AutoGenerateColumns` to  `false`, and add required columns.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="1" Name="gridPatients" >
 <ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding={ Path=FirstName}/>
    ... 
    <DataTemplate>
 </ItemTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```